# D3JS background line chart

Tags: d3.js, background, linechart

I might be googling wrong, but I was wondering if it's possible to create a background (image or color) beneath the line. I would like to create something as the image below.
[image]

I have created a chart, looks something like this with the example data:
[image]

But this is how I imagined it to look a like (don't mind the colors).
[image]

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frnxd882)

```
 var svg,lineGen;

    makeChart();
    function makeChart(){
    // example data
    mobileData = [
    { "uur" : "00", "pageviews":"20"},
    { "uur" : "01", "pageviews":"26"},
    { "uur" : "02", "pageviews":"10"},
    { "uur" : "03", "pageviews":"30"},
    { "uur" : "04", "pageviews":"40"},
    { "uur" : "05", "pageviews":"50"},
    ]

    tabletData = [
    { "uur" : "00", "pageviews":"50"},
    { "uur" : "01", "pageviews":"20"},
    { "uur" : "02", "pageviews":"10"},
    { "uur" : "03", "pageviews":"35"},
    { "uur" : "04", "pageviews":"45"},
    { "uur" : "05", "pageviews":"10"},
    ]

        var WIDTH = 1200,
            HEIGHT = 200,
            MARGINS = {
                    top:20,
                right:20,
                bottom:20,
                left:50
            }
         svg = d3.select("#visualisation"),
            WIDTH = 1200,
            HEIGHT = 200,
            MARGINS = {
                top: 20,
                right: 20,
                bottom: 20,
                left: 50
            },
            xScale = d3.scale.linear().range([MARGINS.left,WIDTH-MARGINS.right]).domain([00,23]),

            yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom]).domain([00,50]),

            xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(xScale)
                .ticks(24)

            yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(yScale)
                .ticks(10)
                .tickPadding(20)
                .orient("left");

        svg.append("svg:g")
            .attr("class","axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (HEIGHT - MARGINS.bottom) + ")")
            .call(xAxis);

        svg.append("svg:g")
            .attr("class","axis axis-y")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + (MARGINS.left) + ",0)")
            .call(yAxis);

         lineGen = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function(d){
                return xScale(d.uur);
            })
            .y(function(d){
                return yScale(d.pageviews);
            });

        svg.append('svg:path')
            .attr('d', lineGen(mobileData))
            .attr('stroke','orange')
            .attr('stroke-width',2)
            .attr('fill','none');

        svg.append('svg:path')
            .attr('d', lineGen(tabletData))
            .attr('stroke','deeppink')
            .attr('stroke-width',2)
            .attr('fill','none');
    }
```

Comment: You are looking for an *Area Chart*. This requires the use of an area path generator [`d3.svg.area`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/SVG-Shapes.md#area) instead of the line generator `d3.svg.line`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with [area](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/SVG-Shapes.md#area). Just add this code:

```
var area = d3.svg.area()
  .x(function(d) { return xScale(d.uur); })
  .y(function(d) { return yScale(d.pageviews); })
  .y1(function(d) { return HEIGHT - MARGINS.bottom });

 svg.append("path")
  .attr("fill", "yellow")
  .attr("d", area(mobileData));
```

I forked your fiddle, [check it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/qcxhaxpu/1/).

Comment: This might be another question, but how can I make the line of tabletData as a table chart?

Comment: What do you mean? Can you provide some example how it should look?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart, but then the line is area (which I have now because of your help), I only want to convert the line of the tabletData into bars.

Comment: It's not a trivial solution. Check this link - https://bl.ocks.org/nanu146/f48ffc5ec10270f55c9e1fb3da8b38f0 Maybe it can help you.